# (CRON) error (grandchild #874 failed with exit status 2)

Tags: configuration, error-handling, cron

I am trying to run a script every other monday using this cron job. (/ect/crontab)

```
45 8 * * mon root expr `date +%U` % 2 >/dev/null || /home/joe/Scripts/test1.sh
```

This morning I checked my /var/log/syslog and found these entries.

```
/USR/SBIN/CRON[874]: (root) CMD (expr `date +)
/USR/SBIN/CRON[872]: (CRON) error (grandchild #874 failed with exit status 2)
/USR/SBIN/CRON[872]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

I also tried typing this directly into the command line while logged in as root.

```
/bin/sh -c "(export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin; expr `date +%U` % 2 >/dev/null || /home/joe/Scripts/test1.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1)"
```

It worked with no output into the syslog. Does anyone know why my cron job is giving this error?

Comment: You'd better keep crontab very simple, just calling scripts that do whatever you want. It will be easier to test and trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percent is a reserved character in cron and must be escaped with a backslash.